# Container that expands to width of an image, yet keeps other buttons and divs contained inside

Tags: css

So I have a site with four main sections. The div for each section has a background image. All four backgrounds are the same size. There are also important elements in the images that I always want to show. In the original version of the page the image would resize depending upon the browser window size but much of the height of the background image was hidden in most cases. So I worked with a guy cleaning up the css and in the process we set the background images to always display 100% height. I was OK with some black background showing through on the sides a bit when necessary as long as I kept the height.

Anyway it worked well. The images expanded and shrank with the browser width, but they always showed the full height of the image. I signed off on the job and it looked good. Until I changed the browser window height (which is something I rarely think to do). Then the elements all spilled out to the right and left of the 4 main divs. I realize now that nothing in the document specifies the width of any section, just the height at 100vh. Only the fact that all four background images have the same dimensions makes it look like there are defined margins.

Is there a simple solution to this? I need to define a right and left border to the page to contain all of the inner divs and buttons, but I want to keep the 4 main divs showing 100% vertical height.

We are using

```
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            min-height: 100vh;
```

to define each of the four divs.
Basically I need a container surrounding the 4 main sections that expands to the width of the images, while still allowing the images to resize with the window, yet it keeps all of the other buttons and divs contained.

The page can be seen here: view-source:http://liquidpropane.io/hold/
It works right now exactly like I want except the buttons spill out the sides if the browser window is too short.

Comment: If you put an image in a element, and that element has no defined `width` value, the element will be the width of the contained image (until the width of the viewport) - [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/oz1w8cv4/). That's probably not what you really want. Also, the code you linked is not the same exact code that is being used for your background image elements, `background-size: cover;` would be more appropriate (probably), but your elements are using `background-size: auto 100%;` - I am not clear on what you want to achieve, but it seems like you need to completely rewrite your code

Comment: Thank You Justin. I was looking at the code for each individual div and did not notice that .container had the background specified that way. I changed it to cover and that solved the issue of containing the other elements. Removing the max size of 1280 px for .container also fixed the width problem on section 1. Now I am back to my original problem though. I cannot have the height of these background images cropped. The top left is crucial, as are other details. I need to make sure they show 100% of the image height. I am OK with black background showing through on the sides.

Comment: You can use `background-size: contain` if you want to make sure the full height is shown. As you mention, depending on the viewport height/width, it might not fill the entire width. [See demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3vaq64fn/)

Comment: Thanks Justin. That solves the background image problem in a slightly different way that we had originally, but it brings back the original problem of all of the inner divs spilling out the sides of the page when the viewport is too short.. I still think the solution would involve some way to wrap a container around the image width of sections 1-4 to define the right and left borders for the other inner elements. I just can't see how. If I don't find a solution I may have to redo the images to taper to a solid tan color on the sides, and use the same solid color for divs 2, 4 and background.

Comment: It's difficult to position elements based on a background-image position, especially when developing a responsive design. As you're seeing, what looks good at one size, can look janky in another. You'd probably want to utilize media-queries to accomplish this, based off of what I've seen. However, I would probably reconsider the background-image based design.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help Justin. In the end I did have to rethink the design. I wanted to keep the idea of using the background collages, but keep the responsive design. I moved the homepage logo out of the background image and into the banner section. Then I moved the important parts of the collage into the center part of the main image, and the less important parts to the sides. That way cropping at the sides will not matter. Finally I decided to remove the rounded text boxes out of sections 1 and 3. I will just use a small bit of landing page text (quite big in a thin font) on those pages and put the bulk of the content in sections 2 and 4. I have not added that text in yet, but the cleaned up version of the background and banner can be seen at http://liquidpropane.io/newhold

I guess the takeaway that is not specific to just my case is that if information in the background image is important and you want a responsive site, then the important part of the image needs to be centered because there is always the likelihood of cropping on the edges.